# How to delete frame from Delphi Component palette?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I created and added a VCL frame to the component tools "templates" palette.
Now I want to remove it from the palette, but I can't find any info on how to do that.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What is the *component "templates" palette*? How did you add it there?

Comment: @KenWhite **[Create, use and delete a component template](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Creating_a_Component_Template)**

Comment: @Sami I searched and read all the help about creating and using templates and that section about deleting was not in any version I could find - thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click right mouse button on your template in 'Templates' page. You'll see popup menu with 'Delete "YourFrameClassName" button" item. Click it and you'll get what you want.

NOTE: Only works in DOCKED layout - see comments.

Comment: you do realize that the documentation is wrong here, because when I rightclick it shows me a list of all the available components sets.

Comment: @Nasreddine When I rightclick a template I have made and which is listed in the "Templates" group, I dont see any lis of available component set. Instead I see a menu with the fourth item `Delete "mytemplatename" Button`. What did you rightclick on?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I'm on D10 Seattle, and I right clicked on a template I have made (which I'm stuck with it now)

Comment: @TomBrunberg it turns out that if you use the classic undocked desktop view you will not have that popup when you right click on the template :).

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
TomBrunberg figured it out - seems to be a bug in that it only works if you are in docked mode.
I was using undocked view.
Switching to docked layout shows the popup menu.